# grok pattern whit telegraf

Tags: pattern-matching, grok, logparser, telegraf-plugins

I have a problem working with grok pattern
My log is similar to the example below

`2023-11-19 13:53:56.024 my-service [http-nio-9004-exec-3] ERROR ErrorTransformer 1700389436-718213 - Error: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://localhost:8000/*******/*******/******/****-*****/resources/**********/pin/nopin?hash=2bbad8abcf3b752a4ea90352361d26c2602`

In the attached sample log, after the word Error: the continuation of the log is not placed on a new line, but in the real sample, the continuation of the log is on a new line.

EX:

Error:

org.springframework

And my grok pattern is similar to the example below

`%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:LogDateTime}\s+%{USERNAME:ServiceName}\s+\[%{DATA:Thread}\]\s+%{LOGLEVEL:LogLevel}\s+%{DATA:LoggerName}\s+%{DATA:ReferenceId}(?:\s+-)?\s+%{DATA:LogType}(?<message>(?:(.|\r|\rn|)*))`

In the sample log, a special situation occurred and after the word Error: the continuation of the log was recorded in a new line, and I failed to find a special pattern for this situation.

[An image of the output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSGd1.png)

The first part of the log has detected all the patterns without any problems, but the second part after the word Error: the continuation of the log is recorded on a new line and the pattern did not work correctly.

I tried different modes at the end of the pattern, but the desired output was not achieved
I got help from https://grokdebugger.com/
%{GREEDYDATA:message} not working